# cv2.line is not working in Rpi 3

Tags: opencv, python-3

model no: RPi 3 B
Software: Python 3.5.3

Problem:
I am using opencv 3.4 .I was trying to draw a line using function cv2.line().But it returns nothing.But the same code was working fine in my laptop  using 
opencv 3.3.
the uploaded code was-

`import numpy as np
import cv2
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
cv2.imshow('line',img)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a python script you need to add

```
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

right after

```
cv2.imshow('line',img)
```

If you are running your code on the python console, you will need to run cv2.startWindowThread() first.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow('line')
cv2.imshow('line',img)
```